# Append dictionaries in one dictionary iteratively?

Tags: python, dictionary, append

My code:

```
i = 0
dict_1 = {}
new_dict_1 = {}
a = ['E', 'F', 'F','F', 'S', 'P']
b = ['11', '22', '33','44', '55', '66']
while i <6:
    dict_1['Letter'] = a[i]
    dict_1['Num'] = b[i]
    new_dict_1 = new_dict_1, dict_1    
    i+=1
print(new_dict_1)
```

**Desired** output:

```
{{'Letter': 'E', 'Num': '11'}，{'Letter': 'F', 'Num': '22'}，{'Letter': 'F', 'Num': '33'}，{'Letter': 'F', 'Num': '44'}，{'Letter': 'S', 'Num': '55'}，{'Letter': 'P', 'Num': '66'}}
```

Current output(non-desired):

```
(((((({}, {'Letter': 'P', 'Num': '66'}), {'Letter': 'P', 'Num': '66'}), {'Letter': 'P', 'Num': '66'}), {'Letter': 'P', 'Num': '66'}), {'Letter': 'P', 'Num': '66'}), {'Letter': 'P', 'Num': '66'})
```

Question:

How can I update the code, so that I can get my desired result?
it seems that using '.update()' is not suitable.

Thanks!

Comment: `[{'Letter': l, 'Num': n} for l, n in zip(a, b)]`…

Comment: And you won't ever get `{{...}, ...}` here; that would be a set, and sets can't contain dicts as values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension -

```
result = [{'Letter':letter,'Num':num} for letter,num in zip(a,b)]
```

Or you can use a map -

```
result = list(map(lambda x:{'Letter':x[0],'Num':x[1]},zip(a,b)))
```

Comment: In this case, list comprehension is fast.